# Integrating Log function using Mathematica

Tags: integration, analytic-functions, mathematica

Dear Stackexchange users,

I would like to integrate the following function using Mathematica as I don't have a way of doing this by hand:

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\log(A-B\cos\theta)\sin^4\theta}{(A-B\cos\theta)^2}d\theta$$

Within Mathematica I apply the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are real and that with $A>0, B>0$ and $A>B$.   Note that Mathematica will quite happily do the following integration:

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\log(A-B\cos\theta)\sin^4\theta}{(A-B\cos\theta)}d\theta$$

I can numerically integrate this but I would like an analytic result if possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Mathematica if you don’t specify the bounds of integration (i.e. if you just say Integrate[..., $theta$] rather than Integrate[..., $\{\theta, 0, \pi\}$] it should usually give you the analytic result - have you tried this?

Comment: I'm trying it now, let me get back to you if Mathematica completes.

Comment: OK, it has returned a result which is utterly enormous. I will plug in $\pi$ and $0$ and subtract from each other and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I substitute $\pi$ and $0$ then do the subtract I get zero and I know I shuldn't.

Comment: @SAMCRO Please edit your post and add the code that you ran.